# Django 1.9 admin - where to put a customized base.css file?

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-admin

I am using the Django 1.9 admin and I copied the base.css file and renamed it base2.css and put it in the directory mysitedirectory\myprojectdirectory\templates\admin\static\admin\css.

In the base.html file, I changed this line so that the base2.css is referenced as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base2.css" %}{% endblock %}" />
```

In my settings.py I have these:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
# UPDATE: added this line below and it works now. 
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates/admin/static/"),
]
```

Django is not seeing the base2.css file. Is the file in the wrong place? Where is it supposed to go? Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the file in:

`mysitedirectory\myprojectdirectory\static\admin\css`

Comment: Thanks...I updated my question with the addition and it is working now.